# PHP: SoapClient no longer working as expected

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm not very experienced with PHP but about a month ago I wrote a script to pull event data from a SOAP Web service to be displayed on digital signage. It had been working fine for a couple of weeks but it had recently broke.

**Here is the relevant PHP code...**

```
$WSDL_URL = 'http://anprodca.active.com/uofg/servlet/ActiveNetWS?wsdl';

$params = array(
    "ws_system_user" => $credentials,
    "resource_ids" => array(intval($facilityID)),
    "dates" => $date,
    "include_linked_resources" => 0,
    "returning_render_customer_id" => 0
);

$soap = new SoapClient($WSDL_URL);
$response = $soap->wsGetResourceBookings($params);
```

... with `$credentials` containing `userName`, `password`, and `keepAlive` values in an array.

When I get it I get the following exception message: `looks like we got no XML document`. I've seen similar posts on stackoverflow about issues with malformed responses due to troublesome invisible characters, but thats not the case here. The response from `__getLastResponse()` appears to be HTML from a redirection of some kind?

---

I am able to still get the desired result using **SOAPUI**. The following is an example of the XML it passes along in a request generated from the [WSDL URL](http://anprodca.active.com/uofg/ActiveNetWS?wsdl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ANWebServices/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:wsGetResourceBookings>
            <ws_system_user>
                <keepAlive>false</keepAlive>
                <password>password</password>
                <userName>username</userName>
            </ws_system_user>
            <resource_ids>
                <entries>27</entries>
            </resource_ids>
            <dates>09/25/2016</dates>
            <include_linked_resources>0</include_linked_resources>
            <returning_render_customer_id>0</returning_render_customer_id>
        </ns1:wsGetResourceBookings>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

Using the trace option and `__getLastRequest()` with SoapClient I got the following XML, which also worked fine when passed with SOAPUI...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:anw="http://ANWebServices/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ANWebServices/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <anw:wsGetResourceBookings>
         <ws_system_user>
                <keepAlive>false</keepAlive>
            <password>password</password>
            <userName>username</userName>
         </ws_system_user>
         <resource_ids>
            <entries>27</entries>
         </resource_ids>
         <dates>09/25/2016</dates>
         <include_linked_resources>0</include_linked_resources>
         <returning_render_customer_id>0</returning_render_customer_id>
      </anw:wsGetResourceBookings>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I assumed that the [WSDL](http://anprodca.active.com/uofg/ActiveNetWS?wsdl) file had changed but it hasn't. 
Nothing server-side had changed, it was still using the same version of PHP with the same configuration, etc. I've tried disabling WSDL caching  as well as the NuSoap library to no avail. I can't seem to figure out why I can't PHP to get a proper response back using SoapClient. Any insight would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: "if the service is giving you a redirect all of a sudden I'm not sure what you expect people here help you with" ... I'm looking to figure out why I can get a valid XML response using SOAPUI but not SoapClient/PHP

"Perhaps they've rate-limited the IP address you're calling it from" ... then it wouldn't work with SOAPUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue on my own-- just posting this in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

Their WSDL file specified the wrong endpoint URL. I just had to explicitly specify it using `__setLocation()`. Now my PHP looks something like this:

```
...
$soap = new SoapClient($WSDL_URL);
$soap->__setLocation($WSDL_URL);
$response = $soap->wsGetResourceBookings($params);
...
```

1 line fix